# I to send a SOAP request to Siebel from a PHP page to insert data. FYI Seibel does not provide WSDL URL for web service

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, siebel

I want to send data from my PHP page to Siebel CRM. As I have seen so may sample that web service provide a WSDL URL which need to invoke and it is very easy using SOAP Client in php. but how it work in siebel as it has no WSDL url, it's provide a WSDL file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siebel does generate and support WSDLs. But not via URLs, one needs admin access to the integration screens to generate WSDLs. Please speak with the administrator of your siebel instance. Also check oracle support pages for step-by-step instructions.

Newer versions of siebel also supports REST webservices. Again, one needs admin access to setup and get the URLs.